# Connecting SharePoint List to Library - displaying tasks (2010)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

This entire site is new to me and, to my knowledge, is all COTS. The employee before me added a custom column (somehow) called "select" to a document library. When the user clicks the "select" button next to their chosen document (in this case a set of arrows), the task list web part above the library displays the tasks/workflow items associated. I was asked to recreate this for another library but am completely clueless how this previous employee was able to create it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have not added a custom column. They have linked two list web-parts on the page using a connection. The selection column will appear when you do this. You can find examples of how to do this here;

https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/link-two-lists-microsoft-sharepoint/

However, in order for there to be tasks associated with a Document Library I suspect there is some underlying workflow that will have been created with SharePoint Designer. This may include tasks like Approve Document or such-like.

If a task is created for a document it stores the document URL under the Related Content field. However I am unsure how you would connect to this field from the Library webpart. If you Edit the page, click on the Document Library web-part and inspect the connection used you should be able to work out what fields they used.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your response. The issue that I'm having is that when I click "connections" nothing happens. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I realize my last sentence above is a bit ambiguous. I meant to say if you look at the connection used in the page you are trying to replicate then this should give you some clues as to how the Document web-part and Task web-parts were linked. Slight word of caution - it is worth making sure you have Sharepoint Designer installed and working so that you can role back the page in-case something odd happens when you are inspecting the connection. I have had some odd behaviour in the past when doing this that has broken my page.

Comment: Just for a resolution - I found out that this wasn't compatible with IE 11 (or has been having issues) which was keeping me from being able to configure the connection. Opened in chrome and voila! It worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this! done! :)